# Calculating the achromatic number of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

A [complete coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_coloring) is a coloring of the vertices of a simple graph so that for every pair of colors there are a pair of vertices with those colors that are adjacent.

The *achromatic number* of a graph is the greatest number of colors which can be used in a complete coloring.

Does there exist a systematic approach for calculating the achromatic number of a graph? I could express the conditions as a complete $k$-coloring as a boolean SAT problem, but I was wondering if there was a better way. Maybe even software for this purpose, already written?